# Acceso a módulos en carpeta inferior desde carpeta superior

Tags: python, importación

Me encuentro con este problema en python que no consigo resolver, constantemente salta el error **AttributeError: partially initialized module 'getConfig' has no attribute 'basePair' (most likely due to a circular import)**

La estructura de archivos es la siguiente:

```
Project
|
|-- _modules
|    |__ files.py
|    |__ globalVars.py
|    |__ utils.py
|
|__ getConfig.py
|__ config.txt
|__ application.py
```

La aplicación se lanza desde application.py

```
import _modules.utils as utils
import _modules.files as files
import _modules.globalVars as gvars
import getConfig as configs
```

Fichero **getConfig.py**

```
try:
  with open("config.txt") as fname:

    lineas = fname.readlines()
    basePair =            lineas[2].split("=")[1].replace("\n", "")

except Exception as e:
  print (e)
```

Fichero **config.txt** con datos random

```
01:APIKEY=xxx
02:APISECRET=xxx
03:MONEDA_BASE=USDT
04:INVERSION_USDT=xxx
05:TAKE_PROFIT=xxx
```

Fichero **globalVars.py** donde necesito poder acceder a la variable *basePair* que se lee en el getConfig.py

```
import os

# ----- paths
basePath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),".."))
filesPath = "_files"
logPath = "logs"

# ----- exchange
globalLimit = 3 * 24 * 2   # days * hours * (calcules per hour)
allSymbols = []
regex = r"^(?!.*(?:EUR|GBP|AUD)\b).*/"+basePair+"$"
chars = 133
```

Entonces, cómo puedo importar desde globalVars, una variable de un fichero que está en una carpeta inferior?

He probado a hacer esto:

```
from ..getConfig import basePair
```

Pero tampoco ha funcionado.
Podría cambiar toda la estructura de ficheros para incluir getConfig dentro de _modules, pero no quiero hacer esto porque debería tocar de nuevo en varios ficheros y aparte el fichero config.txt no lo quiero mover de la raiz.

Comment: Es un problema interesante, pero se necesita un código a la vista para empezar a trabajar y contrastar una solución. Te sugiero reducir tu código al mínimo posible que demuestre el problema y editar la pregunta.

Comment: He reformulado la pregunta y añadido algo del código fuente tal como está en el fichero, aunque no está el 100% del fichero ya que hay muchas variables y funciones que no vienen al caso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un medio de escapar del problema es hacer que el `main.py` instancie todos los recursos compartidos y que los traspase a los módulos como parámetros explícitos o como datos en un área global. La primera alternativa es preferible, pues desacopla los distintos módulos y crea una API reutilizable.

Por tanto, agregaremos un método a `globalVars.py` que se encargará de completar su inicialización, recibiendo como parámetro `basePair`.

```
import os

# ----- paths
basePath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),".."))
filesPath = "_files"
logPath = "logs"

# ----- exchange
globalLimit = 3 * 24 * 2   # days * hours * (calcules per hour)
allSymbols = []
regex = None
chars = 133

def setBasePair(basePair):
    global regex
    regex = r"^(?!.*(?:EUR|GBP|AUD)\b).*/"+basePair+"$"
    print(f"basePair = {basePair}, regex = {regex}")
```

Notese que `basePair` se inicializa con `None`, lo que producirá un error si intentamos utilizarla sin antes definirla. Esto nos ayuda en la depuración de la app.

Las inicializaciones constantes siguen sin cambios.

En el módulo `application.py` primero obtenemos el valor de `basePair` y luego completamos explicitamente la inicialización de `globalVars.py

```
import _modules.utils as utils
import _modules.files as files
import _modules.globalVars as gvars
import getConfig as configs

gvars.setBasePair(configs.basePair)
```

#### Demo

```
basePair = USDT, regex = ^(?!.*(?:EUR|GBP|AUD)\b).*/USDT$
```

Comment: Genial @candid-moe, tu solución ha funcionado pero me ha generado un subproblema que no había tenido en cuenta en la pregunta inicial, y es que la variable regex es usada luego desde otros módulos, por lo que ahora ha dejado ha pasado a ser None en estos otros módulos. Pero al final he podido solucionarlo llamando a *gvars.setBasePair(configs.basePair)* donde lo he requerido y parece que el script ha vuelto a trabajar sin problema. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Python sólo importa módulos que esté en la ruta de búsqueda de módulos. La ruta de búsqueda está en `sys.path` , por lo que python, por defecto, inserta al principio de esta ruta la carpeta que contiene el fichero principal. Es por eso que puedes importar el resto de ficheros python del directorio.

Pero eso no pasa con `_modules/globalVars.py`. Para que pueda importar `getConfig.py` habría que añadir la carpeta superior en la ruta de búsqueda de módulos:

```py
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, "..")

import getConfig as configs
```

El orden es éste, el `sys.path.insert` ha de hacerse antes del import. Pero lo recomendable es que todos los *imports* se agrupen al inicio, algo que se empeñan en hacer algunos linters, lo que dará problemas.

Python no vuelve a importar un módulo que ya ha sido importado. Teniendo esto en cuenta, una alternativa sería asegurarse de importar el módulo `getConfig` en `application.py` antes de importar `_modules/globalVars.py`. Funcionaría, pero no es nada seguro ni recomendable.

Una forma más directa y segura sería importar el fichero mediante la librería [`importlib.util`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib.util). No es algo evidente de hacer, pero en la documentación viene un [ejemplo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importing-a-source-file-directly) que puede servir como guía:

Desde el fichero `_modules/globalVars.py`

```py
import importlib.util
import sys
from pathlib import Path


# importación programática de "../getConfigs.py" como módulo "configs"
# ---
file_path = Path(".").parent / "getConfigs.py"
module_name = "configs"

spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name, file_path)
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
sys.modules[module_name] = module
spec.loader.exec_module(module)
# ---


# uso normal del módulo 'configs'

APIKEY = configs.APIKEY
```

Por pasos:

1. se crea una especificación de módulo referida al fichero con `spec_from_file_location()`
2. se crea el módulo con `module_from_spec()`
3. se inserta en el listado de módulos (o sea, en `sys.modules`)
4. se hace efectiva la importación con `exec_module()`

Seguramente, no necesites tanta sofisticación. Parece que sólo necesitas tener algunos parámetros globales que sirvan para toda la aplicación. Mi recomendación es que uses variables de entorno. El módulo [python-dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/) hace muy fácil tener un fichero de configuración que se cargue al inicio como variables de entorno:

En el fichero `application.py`:

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
```

En el fichero `.env`:

```
APIKEY=xxx
```

En el fichero `_modules/globalVars.py`

```py
import os

APIKEY = os.getenv("APIKEY", "")
```

Comment: Gracias @Chemacortes. La primera solución me funcionó, y la tuya, la he probado en un sandbox aparte para no pisar el código de la primera solución que ya está operativo y me ha funcionado también. Al final, aunque creo que es algo un poco más "enrevesada" que la primera solución, me ha valido para conocer *dotenv*, que hasta ahora no lo había visto nunca ;)